# Can not verify pgp signed text with GnuPGP

Tags: gnupg

Hi I start to learn PGP and try to verify signed text on website.

First I try to verify this message.(It's just example and content does not matter)

https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2009-February/035774.html

I copy message from "-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----" to "-----END PGP SIGNATURE----" then paste and save as message.asc with my text editor in UTF8, LF mode(My PC is Windows).

Next I try to verify this massage.

```
> gpg --search-key dshaw@jabberwocky.com
# import valid key number 3
> gpg --verify message.asc
gpg: Signature made 02/14/09 05:51:13 東京 (標準時)
gpg:                using RSA key C5787FA3EF733C40
gpg: BAD signature from "Faramir.cl (It's a nickname, of course)   <faramir.cl@gmail.com>" [unknown]
```

I think it is caused by character code or line feed code.
I tried to change character code and line feed code but it doesn't verify...

How to verify signed text on the web by GnuPGP?

my env

- Windows 10(Japanese)
- Visual Studio Code
- GnuPGP
- Powershell

gpg version

```
> gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.4
libgcrypt 1.8.2
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: I could not manage to check the signature, either. Maybe, the mailing list software made a subtle change for the web representation of the text (line endings, encodings, etc.). Moreover, the signature could be just broken.

Comment: Thank you.
I think it was web representation issue you said.